# Close excel without VBA alert in python

Tags: python, vba, excel, win32com

I am using python win32com library to read an excel file. Following is the snippet I use.

```
import win32com.client

excel = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open("path.xlsm")
s=workbook.Sheets('Request')
print(str(s.Cells(10,18)).replace(" ","").lower())
workbook.Close()
```

On calling close, a VBA warning pops up. And the program execution stops till I press'OK'. Please help me in ignoring this warning?
I have tried `excel.DisplayAlerts = False` , which didn't help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried `workbook.Close(False)` ?

`excel.EnableEvents = False` will disable Excel Macros.

Comment: What exactly does the warning say?

Comment: It is a custom warning user has put using VBA script. I cannot see the exact logic there. Basically, it is a reminder to save. The same can be seen when I close the excel manually. This warning won't come if I open with macros disabled using excel.

Comment: Then why can you not simply remove that line of code?

Comment: Why is that?   That is the only way to get rid of the warning.

Comment: Oh, is that so? Can I open excel with macros disabled? Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: excel.EnableEvents = False

Comment: It worked!!! You saved me from a lot of trouble. Can you put this as part of the answer so that I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

You can cheat and set:

```
workbook.Saved = True
```

before closing workbook. Excel will treat it as it is already saved.

Comment: So you have to probably set your path as Trusted Location. Excel -> File -> Options -> Trust Center -> Trust Center Settings -> Trusted Locations and add directory where your file path.xlsm is stored.